# MapReduce: Writing Sequence file using Python[Streaming]

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to write the sequence file in MapReduce. I did it with java successfully but I am not sure how to do it with python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop accepts the Streaming command option `-outputformat`. 
To generate output files as Sequence files, use`-outputformat SequenceFileOutputFormat`.

**For example:**

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat\
    -mapper MapperClass \
    -reducer ReducerClass
```

By default, `-inputformat` and `-outputformat` are set as `TextInputFormat` and `TextOutputFormat` respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me.
I am just curious to know, whether this is possible inside the python code. By importing hadoop libraries.

Comment: Yes, if you are using mrjob module to write MapReduce. Check this link [here](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#input-and-output-formats)

Comment: Sadly this is not working.
In java,
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
is working perfectly but when I use it in Terminal as you have shown, it says class could not found. :(

Comment: @MayurBeldar Please pass the complete class name as `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat`.